# clang error messages for qualified names and using declaractions

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, namespaces, clang, name-lookup

Consider the following code.

```
namespace A::B::C::D::E {
    struct X { };
}

namespace B {
    using namespace A::B::C::D::E;
    // or, using A::B::C::D::E::X;
    // or, using X = A::B::C::D::E::X;
}
```

Let's say I use B::X incorrectly in some way and get an error. That error, in clang at least,  will look something like

`error: ... for type A::B::C::D::E::X`.

I'd much rather have the error stated for `B::X`.

Is there a way to configure clang error messages to use  the locations of using declarations, instead of the aliased entity?

Comment: If you use `B::x` incorrectly, compiler does mention only `B::x`. see https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dROyG1

Comment: @P.W [Not necessary](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/V17zsG)

Comment: @VTT: So not always. And the OP wants it to **always** refer to `B::X`

Comment: @P.W that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is good that the compiler uses A::B::C::D::E::X because otherwise it could be ambiguous. Like in the following example:

```
namespace A::B::C::D::E {
    struct X {
      int y;
    };
}

namespace B {
  using namespace A::B::C::D::E;

  void foo() {
    X aa;
    B::X bb;
    aa.y = 0;
  }

  struct X {
    int z;
  };

  void bar() {
    X aa;
    B::X bb;
    aa.y = 0;
  }

}

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

There can be a struct X declared in the B namespace, and then that is B::X and it is necessary to call the other one A::B::C::D::E::X since otherwise they could not be distinguished.

Comment: That is true, but I think clang is capable enough to recognize the difference in our cases. Namely, the use of a *using directive* or *using declaration*, as opposed to type declarations and/or definitions. I don't think the compiler how to treat our cases the same.